# css multilevel dropdown inheritance

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm having a bit of trouble with inheritance. if you expand the first menu item and mouse over you'll see a grey fly-out with a link in it. the link inside inherits the original styles and I'm not sure how to stop it from taking on those styles. i just want them to be the default link style while inside the fly-out. I've tried selectors but i'm not having any luck. ideas?

I put my code up here: http://pastie.org/3388191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

Read your question too fast and didn't see what your real problem was, sorry about that. There's two ways (that I know of) to fix your link problem.

One way is to add the third level menu links to your default style

```
a, #nav ul ul a {
  // YOUR STYLE PROPERTIES
}
a:hover, #nav ul ul a:hover {
  // YOUR STYLE PROPERTIES
}
```

The second way is to assign a class to either the links in the third level menu, or the links in the first and second level menus.

If you assign a class to the third level links, just apply the same styling to that class as your default links.

If you assign classes to the first and second level links instead, and thus remove all link styles like

```
#nav ul a
```

your third level links will automatically get the default link style.

The problem is the use of `#nav a` which applys a styling to **all** links within `#nav`

Comment: maybe its just me, but i can't get it working correctly.. oye

Answer (score 2):

Just use a CSS's [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators), `ul > li` to define the styles to your main list items, that way those styles won't be inherited past your second level subnav, like so:

```
#nav > ul > ul {
    background-color: #999999;
    height: 299px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 652px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kQuGd/1/show/

Comment: i've done that but it messes up the whole nav. i must be missing one somewhere.

Comment: @MatthewDesmond messes up the whole nav how? you mean how the second level subnav  is positioned? that can be fixed easily.

Comment: my background disappears and the style stays the same..
http://pastie.org/3388578

Comment: @MatthewDesmond so you want to remove the green background and all styles from your second level subnav? like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kQuGd/4/

Comment: @MatthewDesmond - He misunderstood your question, just like I did. Changed my answer, so please have another look at it

Comment: thats correct. i want to drop the inherited link styles in the 3rd level flyout

Comment: @MatthewDesmond latest fiddle shows the desired effect, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kQuGd/4/show/), [edit here](http://jsfiddle.net/kQuGd/4/), you can target only the first and second level nav items by using a more specific selector, such as `#nav li > a {...}`, see demo for results.

Comment: wow.. i can't believe i missed that. guess im in a fog from trying to figure it out all morning.. another set of eyes always helps.. thanks a ton for that..

Comment: i have 1 other question if its a quickie.. how can i keep the 2nd lvl li highlighted when i mouse over to the grey area so i know which item i'm viewing?

Comment: @MatthewDesmond switch the hover state from the `<a>` tag to the `<li>` tag, e.g. `#nav li:hover > a { .. }`. If you found the answer satisfactory please mark it as such to help other users with the same problem.

Comment: i was trying 1 other thing. using a 3rd lvl UL is it possible to fix the billboard to the top of the list so it doesnt move down on hover?

Comment: @MatthewDesmond What you call the billboard is the background of the `ul` submenu, to create a non-shifting background just create an absolutely positioned div before the submenu `ul` with the width and height of your choice and a `left` position of `100%`.

Comment: that i tried. but the text still moved down the list rather than staying fixed. im thinking ill need some jquery? then again maybe i didnt do it right.. this is the first dropdown ive built

Comment: @MatthewDesmond try this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kQuGd/5/), edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kQuGd/5/)

Comment: yea, that's about as far as i got. the text within it still moves down and i have a lot of text going in these boards unfortunately

Comment: @MatthewDesmond You can achieve that effect by positioning absolutely the subnav menu items and just include `top:0` for the elements. As an aside, your request is out of scope of your original answer, for further attention please open up another question.